# unit test for Perl's sort

Tags: perl, sorting

I try to use a (class) method in an Object for sorting object instances.

```
package Something; 

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub new {  
    my ($class, $date) = @_;
    my $self = bless{}, $class;
    $self->{date} = $date; 
    return $self;
}

sub _sort($$) {
    print STDERR Dumper($_[0], $_[1]);
    $_[0]->{date} cmp $_[1]->{date};
}

package SomethingTest;

use base 'Test::Class';
use Test::More;

__PACKAGE__->runtests() unless caller;

sub sorting : Test {
    my $jan = Something->new("2016-01-01");
    my $feb = Something->new("2016-02-01");
    my $mar = Something->new("2016-03-01");

    is_deeply(
        sort Something::_sort [$feb, $mar, $jan], 
        [$jan, $feb, $mar]);
}
```

I've seen this snippet in `perldoc -f sort`, hence the prototype for `_sort`.

```
# using a prototype allows you to use any comparison subroutine
# as a sort subroutine (including other package's subroutines)
package other;
sub backwards ($$) { $_[1] cmp $_[0]; }  # $a and $b are
                                         # not set here
package main;
@new = sort other::backwards @old;
```

However, the dumped arguments look odd:

```
$VAR1 = [
      bless( {
               'date' => '2016-02-01'
             }, 'Something' ),
      bless( {
               'date' => '2016-03-01'
             }, 'Something' ),
      bless( {
               'date' => '2016-01-01'
             }, 'Something' )
    ];
$VAR2 = [
      $VAR1->[2],
      $VAR1->[0],
      $VAR1->[1]
    ];
```

and the test fails with

```
#   Failed test 'sorting died (Not a HASH reference at sort.t line 16.)'
#   at sort.t line 25.
```

Is this just my test setup or can't I have the same objects in these arrays?
What else am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the subroutine you pass to `sort()`, but in the arguments you pass to `is_deeply()`. The way you have written it parses like this, if we add some parentheses:

```
is_deeply(
        sort(Something::_sort [$feb, $mar, $jan], [$jan, $feb, $mar] )
    );
```

That is, you're telling `sort()` to act on a list consisting of two anonymous array references, and then `is_deeply()` to run with the single argument returned from `sort` (except it crashes before `is_deeply()` can try to run and complain that you gave it too few arguments to work with).

This is probably closer to what you intended:

```
is_deeply(
          [sort(Something::_sort ($feb, $mar, $jan))],
          [$jan, $feb, $mar]);
```

That is, tell `is_deeply()` to compare two anonymous arrays, the first of which is made from telling `sort()` to apply your sorting routine to the list `($feb, $mar, $jan)`.

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed looking at the wrong place. Your code gets me a compiler error because the sort prototype specifies only 2 arguments (and the code passes 3), but `is_deeply([sort Something::_sort $feb, $mar, $jan], [$jan, $feb, $mar]);` works.